# Urgent: Transit requirements from Jeddah via NYC-JED-Delhi

Tags: transit

I will be flying from NYC-JEDDAH-New Delhi. Do I need to download and register Tawakkaina App or Registration Immunization Information Form? I tried link on immunization form and the translation to english gave the options of "unprotected resident" "fortified resident" "visitor for treatment" "unprotected visitor" "dungeon visitor" "domesticc workers accompanying citizens".

Do I need anything other than negative PCR test result and proof of double-shot vaccine card for transit through Jeddah? Layover is 2 hours.

Guests traveling from Saudi Arabia's airports must present the Tawakkalna App, which shows the state of health, as this will be a condition for entering Saudi Arabia's airports, issuing boarding passes, and boarding the aircraft, according to the rules and regulations of the General Authority of Civil Aviation.
INTERNATIONAL FLIGHTS FROM / TO SAUDI ARABIA:

IMMUNE and Non-immune guests (except Saudi Citizens and exempted categories) must fill out the Registration Immunization Information Form before traveling to the Kingdom through the following dedicated website: https://muqeem.sa/#/vaccine-registration/home allow them to register their immunization data which will enable them to use TAWAKKALNA App.

Comment: "Dungeon visitor"?

Answer (score 1):

Not an an answer but too long for a comment

This seems to be extremely poorly documented. Your choices are

- Call the airline or your booking agent. There also a WhatsApp number on this page https://www.saudia.com/before-flying/travel-information/announcements-and-travel-updates/covid-19
- Contact the airport. There is a 24/7 help desk number nd e-mail address at the bottom a of this page https://www.kaia.sa/en/Pages/default.aspx
- Put all your details in here and see if that helps: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the whatsapp number and did not get a reply.  The website translations from arabic to english are really not helpful either.